# How to redirect to created doc?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I redirect a user to the show action of a doc / post that he've just created using express.js?

Here is the code I'm using to create the doc:

```
app.post('/doc/create', docController.postCreate );
app.get('/doc/:id', docController.getRecord );

exports.postCreate = ((req, res, next) => {

  const doc = new Doc({
    title: req.body.title
  });

  doc.save(req.body, (err /*, result*/) => {
    res.redirect('doc/{{{DOC_ID}}}'); // How can I get/pass the newly created ID
  });

});
```

Comment: you dont get a doc ID here. You need to create one probably basis DateTime Stamp on server or alternatively you may pass the doc title and that id should be used doc title to retrieve file to the browser

Comment: Yes, I know I can't get it there. But how can I get a reference of the doc I'm creating? Can you be more specific with the example you gave? Neverless I'll try passing the title while saving as you say...Thank you

Comment: Yes! That's the solution. I'll pass the timestamp + title in the POST action and get the records by the timestamp + title in the GET action. Thank you @AkshayKhandelwal

Comment: Your problem is not with express and the redirection - your problem is with getting the new created document ID. I don't know with what ORM are you using, but must of them will have the stored data available as the second parameter. You should not use timestamps (This is bad because the chance of conflict is 1:1000 due to the millisecond accuracy, so if 1001 documents are created in the same second, you will have a conflict). So you should be able to use the "id" field of the object you just created, but that depends on the ORM you are using.

Comment: I'm using MongoDB + Mongoose @RonDadon. I can't see the way to get the ID of the newly created doc with Mongoose while posting to db. I see the issue that you are talking about the timestamp... But, I'll do this passing the current user ID to try to avoid conflits.

Comment: I ended up solving this problem creating a **slug** based on the name + **random id ** generated based in a function. Then i redirect to this slug+randomid. e.g: `res.redirect('/doc/' + doc.slug+ '-' + doc.randomid); Thanks to all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database response should return the id of the created item.

```
// ucommment the result param
doc.save(req.body, (err, result) => {
  // ALWAYS handle errors!
  if (err) return res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
  // hopefully, the id is at the root of the result object, else, find out where it is and use it
  res.redirect('/doc/' + result.id);
});
```

Comment: yes! Based in my solution [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907615/how-to-redirect-to-created-doc/37911112#comment63270584_37907615), I found that I could solve it this way, Anyway, I like my solution above. Thank you